# Javascript button is not working as expected

Tags: visualforce, javascript

Whenever any sales rep trying to create a quote i need to check account shipping address <> null.

And if particular account has records with subscriptions i need to pass the url differently or if doesn't have records i need to pass to other url

```
{!REQUIRESCRIPT("/soap/ajax/30.0/connection.js")}
{!REQUIRESCRIPT("/soap/ajax/24.0/apex.js")}

var Subrecords = sforce.connection.query("SELECT Id,name from Zuora__Subscription__c where Zuora__Account__c ='{!Opportunity.AccountId}'");
records = Subrecords.getArray("records");

if(Subrecords.length > 0  && {!ISBLANK(Opportunity.Shipping_City__c)})
{
    window.open('https://zqu.ap4.visual.force.com/apex/CreateQuote?oppId={!Opportunity.Id}quoteType=Subscription&stepNumber=1');
}
else {
    if({!ISBLANK(Opportunity.Shipping_City__c)}){
        alert("Account Shipping address should not be null")
    }
    else {
        window.open('https://zqu.ap4.visual.force.com/apex/CreateQuote?oppId={!Opportunity.Id}&quoteType=Subscription&scontrolCaching=1&stepNumber=2');
    }
}
```

Why is it always redirecting to the second url?

Comment: C'mon man what does this post have to do with Salesforce1 or communities?

Comment: It doesn't have anything to do with remoting either.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think there is something wrong in your conditional checking. It would be like this.

```
if(records.length > 0  && {!NOT(ISBLANK(Opportunity.Shipping_City__c))})
{
    window.open('https://zqu.ap4.visual.force.com/apex/CreateQuote?oppId={!Opportunity.Id}quoteType=Subscription&stepNumber=1');
}
else {
    if({!ISBLANK(Opportunity.Shipping_City__c)}){
    alert("Account Shipping address should not be null")
    }
    else {
        window.open('https://zqu.ap4.visual.force.com/apex/CreateQuote?oppId={!Opportunity.Id}&quoteType=Subscription&scontrolCaching=1&stepNumber=2');
    }
}
```

According to your question, if you can clearly mention in bullet points what conditions you are trying to achieve then my answer will then be more perfect.